# Product of a sub sequence and modulo

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a sequence of prime numbers for instance `3 5 11 3 7 13 5 7 11 13` where each prime number occurs exactly twice you are asked to find product of a certain sub sequence modulo 3 given the left and right indices of this sub sequence.

This was a problem found in [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack27/challenges/special-lcm-of-subarray). I went through the editorial to understand how this problem needs to be solved. I was able to get almost everything except the last part in this piece of code that was written to speed up the process of computing the answer. Attaching the relevant snippets where I need help

```
int A[100004];
int zero[100004],mul[100004];
void solve()
{
    int N,Q;
    mul[0] = 1;
    zero[0] = 0;
    scanf("%d%d",&N,&Q);
    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
        zero[i]  = zero[i-1];
        mul[i] = mul[i-1];
        int z = A[i]%3;
        if( z == 0 ){
            zero[i]++;
        }
        else{
            mul[i] = mul[i]*z;
            mul[i] %= 3;
        }
    }
    int x,y;
    for(int i=1;i<=Q;i++){
        scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
        if( zero[y] - zero[x-1] == 1 )  printf("0\n");
        else{
            printf("%d\n",(mul[y]*mul[x-1])%3);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain how and why the last step works and helps us find the product of the right sub sequence modulo 3?

Comment: You may want to start by generating an array of the same size, containing each element from the original array modulo 3 (i.e., the new array will contain only 0, 1 and 2).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth the input array is indexed starting from 1 in the editorial

Comment: Also, as soon as you get `mul[i] == 0`, then all subsequent elements of `mul` will also be `0`.  That doesn't sound like a viable solution...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I forgot to paste the other two lines that handle this case. Let me do that

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Here you go. I added the entire code snippet so that I don't miss out on anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element of `mul` is the cumulative product (modulo 3) of `A`, with zeros skipped (because as soon as there's at least one multiple of 3 in the sub-range, then the answer must be 0).

`mul[x-1] * mul[y]` is equal to `(A[0]*...*A[x-1]) * (A[0]*...*A[y])`, which is equivalent to `(A[0]*...*A[x-1])^2 * (A[x]*...*A[y])`.  However, that squared term will always be equal to 1 when calculated in modulo 3 (1*1 = 1, 2*2 = 4).  Thus we're left with the desired answer.

**Note:** The zero-handling in the above code is broken.  It doesn't work if there is more than one multiple of 3 in the sub-range.

Comment: I was unable to understand only the last part. This printf statement 'printf("%d\n",(mul[y]*mul[x-1])%3);' Your explanation made it pretty obvious.

Comment: Yes! the zero handling code..the condition should be `>=1`